# How to UPDATE a certain row OR RETURN FALSE if it doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

How to do it in one query?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
function updateValue()
{
     mysql_query($sql); // your update goes here
     return mysql_affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

From BoltClock's comment:

> Bear in mind that mysql_affected_rows() returns 0 if a row exists but the old and new values are equal (meaning there was no need for an update).

Comment: Bear in mind that `mysql_affected_rows()` does not count a row if its old and new values are equal (meaning there was no need to update it). For most cases, though, this does the trick.

Comment: Must count the equal values as a successful update... So that does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You may use mysql_affected_rows() function to check, whether any rows were affected by update. See for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

This is done for you already.

```
if(mysql_query('UPDATE table SET key = value WHERE id = 33')){/*....*/}
```

Using the where clause will check if the id exists and if it does then it will update it, what's the issue?

Comment: The program wants to know whether it exists and is successfully updated or it does not exist.

Comment: Can you please make that requirement more clear in your inital question then?